# How do you directly edit the connection information for power pivot excel?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Good day, I am trying to directly alter the connection information (sql statement and connection string) for power pivot from the xml files.

The connection name is stored within the `connections.xml` file but it does not have the sql statement or connection string. I have a `item.data` file within the `xl/model` folder but the encoding does not allow me to view all the content.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's an interesting question. Your issue seems analogous to one I've experienced in VBA - I can see Power Pivot connections, but not the connection string or sql. Please leave an answer if you figure it out. Good luck!

Comment: You can use the following c# code to view the connection information, however it does break when you try and change the information which is why I want to directly reference `item.data`

Comment: Application app = new Application();
app.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
foreach (Workbook workbook in app.Workbooks)
{
foreach (WorkbookConnection connection in workbook.Connections)
{
string connectionString = connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection.ToString();
string sqlCommand = connection.OLEDBConnection.CommandText;
}

                workbook.Close();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
            }

            app.Workbooks.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app.Workbooks);

            app.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);

Comment: Thanks I know how to do that. I was trying to find the Oracle connection and query, the native query, inside of power query. I may be confused, but I think that's a different issue, and one that I couldn't solve.